# Is there a more elegant way to initialize empty dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance

```
isd = pd.DataFrame()
ind = pd.DataFrame()
exd = pd.DataFrame()
psd = pd.DataFrame()
visd = pd.DataFrame()
vind = pd.DataFrame()
vexd = pd.DataFrame()
sd = pd.DataFrame()
ise = pd.DataFrame()
idb = pd.DataFrame()
mdd = pd.DataFrame()
add = pd.DataFrame()
```

Is there any alternate way to make it elegant and faster?

Comment: Are you planning do use similar code for some of these dataframes?

Comment: yes the code is almost the same for each dataframe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a dictionary of dataframes, especially of the code for some data frames is going to share some similarities. This will allows doing some operations using loops or functions:

```
dct = {n: pd.DataFrame() for n in ['isd', 'ind', 'exd']}
```

Comment: df_names = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
df_list = [pd.DataFrame() for df in df_names] is this also valid?

Comment: @SaadSaleem: Yes, it is also valid. But usually it is easier to refer to individual data frames by keys ("names") than by indexes of a list ("numbers"). Thus, I prefer a dictionary to a list, but YMMV.

Comment: @Time Shtatland: I saw this method somewhere but am having doubts. isd,ind,exd,psd,visd,vind,vexd,sd,ise,idb,mdd,add=(pd.DataFrame,)*12

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid needing to numerically index each of the DataFrames, but would rather be able to access them directly by their name:

```py
import pandas as pd

table_names = ['df1', 'df2', 'df3']
for name in table_names:
  exec('%s = pd.DataFrame()' % name, locals(), locals())

print(df1)
```

This approach uses [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec), which essentially runs a string as if it were python code. I'm just formatting each of the predetermined names into the string in a for-loop.

Answer (score -1):

<s>I think you can go this way</s>

```
import pandas as pd

a, b, c, d = [pd.DataFrame()]*4
```

Comment: There's one big caveat with this approach: Run this code and then `c['foo']=[1]; print(a)`

Comment: You right it's definitely not the way to go, thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```
dfs = ['isd', 'ind', 'exd']
df_list = [pd.DataFrame() for df in dfs ]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).